# Perforce Integrate - how to force solution when files are equal

Tags: perforce-integrate

Suppose That 2 different branches include a file that is exactly the same, except its revision number.
How can I force "p4 integrate" to automatically take the higher-revision branch without using "p4 resolve"?

Thanks.

Comment: There's no way for p4 integrate to know this is what you want, so the only way I can conceive of how to do it is through scripting. Pretty sure you'll have to do some scripted resolves, though.